# onKey in EditText build programatically Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've a problem with onKey. I've build some EditText programatically, I want to focus de next EditText when press enter, I know do it, but the onKey just is called when I press back, could somebody help me?? thanks

```
        layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listajugadores);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0);
        et_jugadores = new ArrayList<EditText>();
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();


        for (int i = 0; i < bundle.getInt("num_jugadores"); i++) {
            EditText et_aux = new EditText(this);
            et_aux.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            et_aux.setHint(getString(R.string.jugador) +" " + String.valueOf(i+1));
            et_aux.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sh_edit_text);
            et_aux.addTextChangedListener(textwatcher);
            et_aux.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    Log.d("KEY","aaaaa");
                    return false;
                }
            });
            et_jugadores.add(et_aux);
            layout.addView(et_aux,layoutParams);                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this if

```
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                //do something here
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: The problem isn't the if, the problem is that the onKey method, only is called if I press back